# Creating and distributing jar files in Android

Tags: android, jar, android-library

In my android application I have to separately implement a certain functionality and needs to make a **library file(.jar)** out of it.

Main idea is then I can distribute that jar file, so that other applications can easily integrate this functionality using the jar file within their apps.

Following I have indicate the Minimum and Target SDK versions that are in the Manifest file.

```
 android:minSdkVersion="7"
 android:targetSdkVersion="15"
```

I know I can create a library project to implement that specific functionality and have a reference for it from my main project. And then to **distribute** the jar file that creates under the bin folder of the library project.

I have couple of questions reagrding this.

1) Since I didn't find any good tutorial explaining this thing, bit not sure if this is the way to go (Distributing the **jar** file creates under bin folder).

2) Also the jar file that creates under the bin folder of the library project is with the same project name(Eg:- LibraryProjectName.jar). Is it okay if I rename it for what I want before I distribute it?

3) Are there any other alternative or good ways of doing this?

Any help would be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/tools/projects/projects-eclipse.html. http://developer.android.com/tools/projects/index.html

Comment: Yes I can create and refer to a library project like from my main project. The bit I want to know is, if it's alright to distribute the jar file that creates under the bin folder for others to get this functionality integrated in their apps.

Comment: unzip your jar and see the contents. does the jar contain pure java classes?

Comment: If I unzip and check the content I can see the class. But its not readable. Not pure java classes

Answer (score 0):

> Since I didn't find any good tutorial explaining this thing, bit not sure if this is the way to go(Distributing the jar file creates under bin folder).

I wouldn't. That JAR is an artifact of consuming the library project and may or may not be suitable for third parties. Besides, if you really need an Android library project, the JAR is insufficient.

> Is it okay if I rename it for what I want before I distribute it?

JAR names can be whatever you want.

> Are there any other alternative or good ways of doing this?

First, do not create an Android library project unless you need to ship resources along with the code (or JAR). And, in that case, you will need to distribute the JAR *and all the resources* (and the manifest and pretty much everything else in the project).

Second, create your own JAR, such as by adding a `<jar>` operation to your Ant script. That way, *you* are in control over exactly what goes in there, how it got compiled, etc., rather than making assumptions about the JAR that the build system created as a by-product.

For example, here is a `jar` target from one of my CWAC projects:

```
<target name="jar" depends="debug">
    <jar
        destfile="bin/CWAC-EndlessAdapter.jar"
        basedir="bin/classes"
    />
</target>
```

Comment: Hi CommonsWare, It's going to have only one class in my android library project with some public methods in it. It's not going to use any resourses or any layouts or anything. Just a logic(Functions that communicate with web services and providing the ultimate result back)..... Just to test I removed the reference to the libarary project and added that JAR file in to main project (to Java build path) instead. And it worked fine as it was with reference to the library project earlier. Thats Why I thought it will be okay to distribute this JAR file for 3rd parties to use.

Comment: @JibW: We have been told not to consider that JAR to be safe for redistribution. Considering that running a `jar` command yourself takes seconds -- less time than it took you to write your question and comment -- I would strongly encourage you to create your own JAR, so you are responsible for (and have control over) its contents.

Comment: Hi CommonsWare, Thank you very much for your support and yes it's always good to follow the good practices. I tried to export the project to a JAR file but it didn't work. I believe for sure I must have done a mistake while creating(Export) the JAR file. If you can explain the steps that I have to follow to create a JAR file out of the Library project manually then it would be great. I am using eclipse. Thanks....

Comment: @JibW: Personally, I do not create my JARs from Eclipse, but from the command line through Ant. I am sure there is a process in Eclipse for what you are trying to do; I just cannot provide you with those steps. Sorry!

Comment: If you don't mind would you like to explain how I can create a JAR file using the command line through Ant. Trying to figure it out with eclipse. No luck yet...  Thank you.

Comment: Bit confused as I haven't used command line with Ant before. But Thanks I'll have a look at this. Hope this will work out.

Comment: @JibW: Sorry, but I cannot readily teach you how to use Ant, in its entirety, in StackOverflow comments. http://ant.apache.org has a manual, and there is plenty of other (non-Android) material on Ant, as it has been popular in Java development for a decade-plus.